# Сервер - Клиент. Рейтинг

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c++-cli

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разумнее\правильнее изменять информацию в файлах на сервере с компьютера клиента?

Суть: Есть программа, лаунчер игры, у игры есть моды, лаунчер поддерживает закачку с сервера модов, автоматическую установку их и запуск. Я загорелся идеей ввести рейтинг модов, чтобы каждый пользователь мог проголосовать +- за каждый мод. Единственная идея как это реализовать заключается в том чтобы хранить на сервере xml файл с записями о модах и их рейтинге. С клиентской же стороны скачивать этот файл в момент нажатия на кнопку + или - и изменять его  (а так же помечать на компьютере клиента что он уже сделал свой голос), а затем закачивать уже измененный файл обратно с заменой. Я планирую сделать это по ftp, однако, этот протокол очень долгий.

Вопрос: как сделать данную систему как можно проще и как можно быстрее(в плане производительности)? Может быть можно из моей программы както подключаться не к серверу а бд на MySQL?

p.S: Моя программа на .NET (не вижу смысла тут конкретнее указывать язык)

Comment: А зачем если уже есть шаблоны разработки для клиент-серверной архитектуры? Клиент шлёт запрос серверу, который его обрабатывает и возвращает ответ. Клиент не должен иметь прав менять что-то на сервере просто так, иначе любой может наменять так что мама не горюй. Запросы от клиента должны обрабатываться сервером, определяются права клиента на действие, и уже только после этого сервер будет обрабатывать запрос на действие.

Comment: К сожалению я не сильно разбираюсь в сетях, к тому же у меня дешевенький хостинг расчитаный под сайт, а я так понимаю что вы про что-то вроде ASP.NET итд. Однако, мой сервер поддерживает только такие технологии: HTML, PHP, MySQL, FTP, JS, AJAX... Я мало что в этом понимаю, но если что то из этого может подойти под ваше описание, прошу подкинуть ссылочку на материал который мне может помочь. К слову у меня в программе есть окошечко WebBrowser в котором чатик на php и mysql расположенный на сервере)

Comment: Тогда вам на php.ru

Comment: А разве можно связать контрол WinForms Button с php скриптом на сервере? И если да, то для меня это основная сложность!

Comment: отправляй REST запрос в виде строки .  И обрабатывай на сайте

Comment: Уже решил проблему. На сервере написал пхп скрипт принимающий переменные POST. В программе создаю NameValueCollection и отправляю через weBclient UploadValues прямо на url .php файла. Быстродействие примерно пол секунды, но я всеравно запихал функцию в отдельный поток, и все получилось очень приятненько. Спасибо всем за идеи.